# wp_mail() method not sending email in some cases

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

That is my code for sending email via `wp_mail()` method

```
$user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
$subject = 'Account is ready.';
$message = "Hello <b>$user_name</b>,a new account created for you and you need to create a password, <a href'http:example.com/account?email=$user_email'>click here</a>  to create a password and login.";

$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

$mail = wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($mail){
    echo 'Sent email to user.';
}
 else {
    echo 'Oops something went wrong to sending email.';
}
```

actually that didn't work I mean not sending the email to user, while modify the `wp_mail()` method like this

```
$mail = wp_mail($user_email, $subject, $message);
```

that's working, that the mean it never taken more than three parameters, but I need to add `$headers` for HTML.

What can I do now?

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: check this link https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/wp-mail/

Comment: Yes the concept is same but more than three parameters in wp_mail() it's not sending email

Comment: try instead mail() function

Comment: Yes! tried and not luck

Comment: $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "FROM: your email <youremail.com>\r\n";
$email = 'youremail.com';
$msg='your msg';
mail($email,'your subject',$msg,$headers);

Comment: You are using the value from `$_POST` without any sanitization nor validation?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wp_mail docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#using-headers-to-set-from-cc-and-bcc-parameters) the headers parameter is used to set From, CC and BCC fields. It might not set other fields.

To set your content type and character set you need to use another function, please see linked docs.
Mail is send in plain text by default, to send it as HTML you should also consult linked docs as the method to switch to HTML is also there.

Answer (score -1):

Have you setup, SMTP settings in WordPress panel if not you can use Many plugins to setup you can use m fav plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/
Try to set up this plugin and after let me know if you still facing those issues

Comment: Since without the headers parameter OP states it is working I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: @Jonathan Not only `headers` it working with only three parameters, if I remove `headers` or `subject` or `body`